# #value error in Excel with a very simple function

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two columns of numbers: I want to divide one column by the other. Simple!

Column A and B both have "numbers" in them. I have checked, stripped all formatting, made sure there were no errant spaces or other punctuation. The numbers are all whole numbers. No decimals.

I get a #value! error EVERY TIME. When I do Error Checking, The value used in the formula is the wrong  Data Type.

I have tried changing the type from general to number, and back again. I have validated the data to make sure they are "values" not text to something else.

I am not sure what else to do! Help?

Comment: What is the formula you are using? Also can you show a picture of the some of the data?  Also post some of the data as text here?

Comment: Please check for transparent characters before and after the numbers of two cells(such as space).

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are dividing a number from A1 by a number from B1, try this:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(A1)/NUMBERVALUE(B1)
```

The NUMBERVALUE function will force the data type to numeric where possible.